# Reload a directive on controller event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

I have a directive which is fetching data through ajax on load. But after an event in the controller which is posting some data, the Directive should re-compile with the new ajax data so that the changes can be reflected. Can you please help.

I have a compile function in the directive which takes data and puts that in HTML file and generates markup.

Then I have a save comment function in the controller which saves a new comment and so the directive gets the new data.

```
compile: function(tElement, tAttrs) {
      var templateLoader = $http.get(base_url + 'test?ticket=' + $routeParams.ticketid, {cache: $templateCache})
          .success(function(htmlComment) {
            if (htmlComment != '')
              tElement.html(htmlComment);
            else
              tElement.html('');
          });
      return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        templateLoader.then(function (templateText) {
          if (tElement.html() != '')
            element.html($compile(tElement.html())(scope));
          else
            element.html('<div class="no-comments comment"><p>Be the first to comment</p></div>');
        });
      };
    }
```

This is the compile part of the directive. I want this to be called through a normal controller event.

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: added my code, I hope this helps.

Comment: do you want to use compile function? Because I do not think it's required as the expected output can be achieved without it?

Comment: See I will give you the full context. I am getting threaded comments with markup from PHP. I tried doing that in Angular but found it to be a bit difficult without calling the same template again and again and increase HTTP request. So, the threaded comments are coming, but when I add a new comment, I was to re-compile the directive so that the new comment in visible.

Comment: what about just using ng-bind-html instead? and make the controller responsible for querying the markup?

Comment: @mpm: Yeah, that's what I was thinking.

Comment: @mpm can you show me an example.. where the controller does a ajax call and the response HTML is fetched and displayed? Thanks in advance

Comment: @AmitavRoy: Do you receive all the added comments when a new one is saved? or Just the recent one?

Comment: I can get both, right now on click of Save button through ng-save I am able to save the data. But because the whole comment section is a single directive, I am not able to change the markup. Or else I could have used a broadcast or something to update the scope variable and an ng-repeat would have worked.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend @Riley Lark' response but as you already mentioned that your API returns an HTML instead of JSON, here is my take.

Your controller as:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <button ng-click="save()">Save Comment</button>
    <comments></comments>
</div>


myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.commentHTML = '';
  $scope.alert = function(salt) {
    alert('You clicked, My Comment ' + salt);
  }
  $scope.save = function() {
    // this imitates an AJAX call
    var salt = Math.random(1000);
    $scope.commentHTML+= '<div ng-click="alert(' + salt + ')">My Comment ' + salt + '</div>';    
  };
});
```

And the comments directive as:

```
myApp.directive('comments', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function(scope, element) {
      scope.$watch(function() { return scope.commentHTML; }, function(newVal, oldVal) {
        if (newVal && newVal !== oldVal) {
          element.html(newVal);
          $compile(element)(scope);
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Hope this solves your problem..!

<kbd>[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/codef0rmer/2d88W/)</kbd>

Comment: looks like this can help

Comment: @AmitavRoy: If that's what you want then why do you need a directive. You can simply use `<div ng-bind-html-unsafe="commentHTML"></div>` as a replacement for `<comments>` unless the directive is outside the controller.

Comment: Yes it's inside the controller, right now I am trying the bind-html-safe method. Looks like the directive is an overkill for this purpose. May be then I will try the above solution separately.. thanks for the help man...

Comment: Hmm the approach worked, but the problem is that if I have ng-click on the new markup, it doesn't work. It's same as using jQuery.on or jQuery.live function with new DOM elements. Any solution for this?

Comment: No angular features will work with this method because it avoids the mechanisms that angular uses to operate. See my answer for a different tack!

Answer (score 0):

After you fetch the data you need, put the data in a `$scope` property. Define your template in terms of that property and it will automatically change when the data returns.

For example, your template might be

```
<div ng-repeat="comment in comments">
    {{comment}}
</div>
```

You don't need a `compile` function or to "reload a directive" to accomplish this.  The solution you posted is a sort of reimplementation of angular. It looks like you want to download a template with the data already interpolated into it, but Angular will help you the most if you separate the template from the data and let Angular interpolate it on the client.